# Select into Table from Table2 where column in (Subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, select-into

```
SELECT .... ColumnNames ...
INTO [FOUND_DUPLICATES] 
FROM [FIND_DUPLICATES] AS FD
WHERE FD.[Contract No] IN 
    (SELECT [Contract No],
            [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)],
            COUNT(*) AS Anzahl 
    FROM FIND_DUPLICATES
    GROUP BY 
            [Contract No],
            [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)]
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
```

Here u can see what I want :)

Find duplicates and copy them to another table.
But with this code I get an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

The SELECT statement to find the duplicates is working very well. But I have a problem to select and copy only the duplicates to the new table with Select Into.

I hope u can understand what I want and anyone can help me with that :)

//EDIT:
Im using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Hmmm... my indentation is slightly wrong there, but that should help readability anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another sub query should work?

```
Select  .... ColumnNames ...

INTO [FOUND_DUPLICATES] 
    FROM [FIND_DUPLICATES]
    AS FD
    where FD.[Contract No] 
       IN (  Select [Contract No] from (Select 
        [Contract No],
        [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)],
        COUNT(*) AS Anzahl 
    from FIND_DUPLICATES
    group by 
        [Contract No],
        [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)]
    having count(*) >1)x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT  .... ColumnNames ...

INTO [FOUND_DUPLICATES] 
FROM [FIND_DUPLICATES] AS FD
WHERE FD.[Contract No] IN
(
  SELECT 
    [Contract No]
  FROM FIND_DUPLICATES
  GROUP BY 
     [Contract No],
     [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)]
  HAVING COUNT(*) >1
)
```

or use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT .... ColumnNames ...

INTO [FOUND_DUPLICATES] 
FROM [FIND_DUPLICATES] AS FD
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM FIND_DUPLICATES FD1
    WHERE FD.[Contract No] = FD1.[Contract No]
    GROUP BY 
        FD1.[Contract No],
        FD1.[Vehicle Identity number (VIN)]
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  .... ColumnNames ...

INTO [FOUND_DUPLICATES] 
    FROM [FIND_DUPLICATES]
    AS FD
    where FD.[Contract No] 
       IN (
       select [Contract No] from (Select --inner sub query 
        [Contract No],
        [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)],
        COUNT(*) AS Anzahl 
    from FIND_DUPLICATES
    group by 
        [Contract No],
        [Vehicle Identity number (VIN)]
    having count(*) >1) )
```